# Apache poi BooleanFunction.OR not working properly in array formula

Tags: apache-poi

Update: the bug is fixed in https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65915

I have a spreadsheet with only one cell having the below formula

```
=INDEX({1},1,
IF(OR(FALSE,FALSE),1,1))
```

Now when I use apache poi version 5.2.0 to read this spreadsheet and evaluate all, it failed to evaluate this cell.

The stacktrace shows that the formula is considered to be an array formula and hence BooleanFunction.OR can only accept 1 argument.

Is this expected behavior for apache poi?

Am I missing something? Any thoughts?

Steps to reproduce

```
try (HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook()) {
  HSSFFormulaEvaluator fe = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(wb);
  HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
  HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
  sheet.setArrayFormula("INDEX({1},1,IF(OR(FALSE,FALSE),1,1))", new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 0));
  // this assertion will fail
  org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(fe.evaluate(cell).getNumberValue(), 1.0);
}
```

Stacktrace, see ptg 4 evaluation below.

```
[POI.FormulaEval]W   - evaluateFormula('Sheet1'/A1): [[ArrayPtg] nRows = 1 nCols = 1   {1}, IntPtg [1], BoolPtg [FALSE], BoolPtg [FALSE], FuncVarPtg [OR nArgs=2], AttrPtg [if dist=7], IntPtg [1], AttrPtg [skip dist=10], IntPtg [1], AttrPtg [skip dist=3], FuncVarPtg [IF nArgs=3], FuncVarPtg [INDEX nArgs=3]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 0: [ArrayPtg] nRows = 1 nCols = 1   {1}, stack: []
[POI.FormulaEval]I       = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 1: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.IntPtg [1], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I       = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 2: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.BoolPtg [FALSE], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I       = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.BoolEval [FALSE]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 3: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.BoolPtg [FALSE], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.BoolEval [FALSE]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I       = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.BoolEval [FALSE]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 4: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.FuncVarPtg [OR nArgs=2], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.BoolEval [FALSE], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.BoolEval [FALSE]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I       = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 5: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.AttrPtg [if dist=7], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 6: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.IntPtg [1], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I       = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 7: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.AttrPtg [skip dist=10], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 8: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.IntPtg [1], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I       = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 9: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.AttrPtg [skip dist=3], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 10: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.FuncVarPtg [IF nArgs=3], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I       = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!]
[POI.FormulaEval]I     * ptg 11: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.FuncVarPtg [INDEX nArgs=3], stack: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CacheAreaEval[A1:A1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval [1], org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!]]
[POI.FormulaEval]I       = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!]
[POI.FormulaEval]I   finshed eval of A1: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!]
[org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator]D Evaluated Sheet1!A1 to org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval [#VALUE!]
```

Comment: This formula is nonsense.

Comment: Not reproducible using `apache poi 5.2.0`. For me even that nonsense formula gets evaluated without throwing a exception.

Comment: It won’t throw exception, just ErrorEval. @AxelRichter Did you open the spreadsheet as opcpackage?

Comment: Well it might be that `apache poi` evaluates `OR(FALSE,FALSE)` different from Excel when in array context. And how `apache poi` evaluates it might even be wrong. But nevertheless that whole formula is nonsense. So for me there is no reason to investigate further. Please show a not nonsense example.

Comment: I added a unit test to POI trunk and it seems to work (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65915#c4)

Comment: @PJ Fanning: That evaluation problem only occurs when in array context. So it occurs when evaluating `row = sheet.createRow(0); cell = row.createCell(0); sheet.setArrayFormula("INDEX({1},1,IF(OR(FALSE,FALSE),1,1))", new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 0)); cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell);`. And Office 365 always puts that kind of formula in array context because of the silly new dynamic array formulas and spilled array behavior.

Comment: @AxelRichter I know it’s kinda nonsense formula. I simplified the original formula which has the first argument for the INDEX being a real table with data, and the two arguments for the IF being useful checks. But the point is that if formula in array context, why does BooleanFunction only support 1 argument?

Comment: @PJFanning thanks for looking into this. As Axel said, it can only be reproduced if the formula is under array context, which is the case when I create the workbook from the spreadsheet.xlsx

Comment: I added the steps to reproduce to the post body.